# Display service output on console using systemctl

Tags: linux, systemctl, tty

I have following service file -

```
[Unit]
Description=Open VPN Agent
After=syslog.target
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
TTYPath=/dev/pts/0
KillMode=process
PIDFile=/opt/openVPN/pids/openvpnAgent.pid
ExecStart=/opt/openVPN/openvpnAgent start
ExecStop=/opt/openVPN/openvpnAgent stop
SuccessExitStatus=143
StandardOutput=tty

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I connect to SSH and run tty command, if output is "/dev/pts/0", in that case only output is displayed on console.
If "tty" command gets different value, then output is does not get displayed on console. And with every SSH session, "tty" command's value is different.
How to set "TTYPath" generic so that output gets displayed for any "tty"?

Comment: Don't try to do this. It is not possible anyway. Let the system log normally and view the logs yourself when necessary.

Comment: But there is need to display output explicitly  on console? What can be done for that? Any other options?

Comment: @user784524 `tail -f /path/to/log/file`

Comment: Use `journalctl` as normal.